# How to avoid hosting restart when deploying Azure Functions with deployment slot?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-functions-runtime, azure-deployment-slots

I configured pipeline to do zero down time deployment for Azure Functions. For that purpose I have following steps:

- create slot
- deploy to slot
- start swap with preview
- complete swap

My understanding of this is process is that all restarts should happen only on preview slot (so only JobHost should be restarted) and this should have a place before final swap. However, I noticed on Application Insight that `Hosting stopped` which result in on `503` code when I was hitting function. Is there away of avoiding this? I'm not sure if it matters but I use Premium plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve zero downtime deployment setting variable `WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG` to `1`. For more info you can take a look [here](https://medium.com/@yapaxinl/azure-deployment-slots-how-not-to-make-deployment-worse-23c5819d1a17). One drwaback of this is slowness on processing requests during deployment.

I also recommend to follow [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/862) where is discussion about zer/miniam downtime deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid the restart but you could use a custom [warm-up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#Warm-up) if your function needs it.

The swap operation waits for the warm-up to finish before swapping with the target swap. You configure this in a `web.config` file, example below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization>
        <add initializationPage="/" hostName="[app hostname]" />
        <add initializationPage="/Home/About" hostName="[app hostname]" />
    </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

You can also customize the warm-up behavior with one or both of the following app settings:

- WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_PATH: The path to ping to warm up your site. Add this app setting by specifying a custom path that begins with a slash as the value. An example is /statuscheck. The default value is /.
- WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_STATUSES: Valid HTTP response codes for the warm-up operation. Add this app setting with a comma-separated list of HTTP codes. An example is 200,202 . If the returned status code isn't in the list, the warmup and swap operations are stopped. By default, all response codes are valid.